# Flask cannot open at 127.0.0.1?

Tags: python, flask, localhost

I'm trying to run the most basic possible app on Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import reddit_text_to_speech  # This is a script converted from my Jupyter notebook and intended to be used in def index() once this is resolved.

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

However, I'm getting this on my Chrome:

> This site can’t be reached

> 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

[image]

According to CMD, it looks like its running:

[image]

I also have Jupyter Lab running on http://localhost:8888/, but since its port 8888 it should not conflict?

Comment: Couple of silly questions, but... Did you specify the port to the browser? http://localhost:5000/ (or http://127.0.0.1:5000/)? Are you actually running your Flask app on the same machine as Chrome (i.e. not on a remote, not in a Docker...)?

Comment: Make sure that Chrome is not trying to establish a secure connection (i.e. `https`).

Comment: Yes i attached the picture onto my question. Unsecure connection. Flask app is on CMD by running `python3 app.py`. Thank you @Amadan 127.0.0.1:5000 worked!

Comment: `http://example.com` goes to port 80. `https://example.com` goes to 443. For any other port you have to specify it in the URL, otherwise how would the browser know?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, specifying the port on Chrome worked:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000`